# What's the first block in MoveAbsolute for programming the T-Rex, in The LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 Laboratory book?

Tags: mindstorms, ev3

On MoveAbsolute2 and 1 for *The LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 Laboratory* book by Daniele Benedettelli, programming the T-Rex, I don't know what the first block is, can i please have help?

Comment: Can you post a picture for those of us that don't have the book?

Comment: I believe David was asking for a picture of the blocks you're trying to locate, rather than a picture of the book.